# ReactJS Context API not updating refreshing the view correctly

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-context

I have setup a reducer based context for my Ionic app that i am developing using ReactJS. My expectation was that useEffect will call the reducer and add the data to properties array in the store and the render would then use this to render the value on the view. However this is not happening, if am not wrong, the page is rendered before the reducer can fetch the value from API. However I cannot confirm this from the console logging.

PropertyReducers.js

```
import { useReducer } from "react";
import propertyservices from "../../service/propertyservices";

const propertyReducer = (state, action) => {
  let newData = { ...state };
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GETPROPERTYS": {
      propertyservices
        .getPropertys(action.mobileNumber)//axios call that fetches data through API 
        .then((response) => {
          let props = [...response.data[0]];
          newData.properties = [];
          props.map((p) => {
            let property = {};
            property.name = p.PropertyName;
            let address = new Address();
            address.addressLine1 = p.Line1;
            address.addressLine2 = p.Line2;
            address.city = p.City;
            address.state = p.State;
            address.pin = p.Pin;
            newData.properties.push(property);
          });
        });
      break;
    }
  }
console.log("reducer returning");
  return newData;
};

const PropertyReducer = () => {
  const [propertyState, propertyDispatch] = useReducer(propertyReducer, {
    properties: [],
    property: {
      address: {
        addressLine1: "123",
        addressLine2: "Street name, some place",
        city: "SomeCity",
        state: "SomeState",
        pin: "123456",
      }
    }
  });
  return { propertyState, propertyDispatch };
};

export default PropertyReducer;
```

DisplayPropertys.tsx

```
import {
  IonText,
  IonPage,
  IonHeader,
  IonToolbar,
  IonButtons,
  IonMenuButton,
  IonTitle,
  IonContent,
  IonButton,
  IonGrid,
  IonRow,
  IonCol,
  IonIcon,
  IonItem,
} from "@ionic/react";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Page.css";
import { trashOutline, pencilOutline } from "ionicons/icons";
import { Redirect, useHistory } from "react-router";
import Context from "../../store/Property/PropertyContext";

const DisplayPropertys: React.FC = (props) => {
  const { propertyState, propertyDispatch } = useContext(Context);

  const refreshView = () => {
    propertyDispatch({
      type: "GETPROPERTYS",
      mobileNumber: '1234567890',
    });
  };

   useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect");
    refreshView();
  }, [propertyState.properties.length]);


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <IonPage>
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonButtons slot="start">
              <IonMenuButton />
            </IonButtons>
            <IonTitle>Propertys</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>

        <IonContent fullscreen>
        {console.log(propertyState)}
          {propertyState.properties && (
            <IonGrid>
              {propertyState.properties.map((property: any) => (
                <IonRow key={property.propertyID}>
                  <IonCol>
                    <IonItem>
                      <IonText>{property.name}</IonText>
                      <IonButton
                        onClick={() => {
                          handleDelete(property.PropertyID);
                        }}
                        slot="end"
                      >
                        <IonIcon icon={trashOutline}></IonIcon>
                      </IonButton>
                    </IonItem>
                  </IonCol>
                </IonRow>
              ))}
            </IonGrid>
          )}
        </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default DisplayPropertys;
```

[image]

As you can see the call was successfully and properties array was populated, but the renders happened after that still does not have the right state. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies on your `useEffect` do not make sense.  It's the type of thing that can create an infinite loop if you aren't careful.  If the length of the properties array changes then you run the effect, which calls `refreshView`, which calls `propertyDispatch`, which triggers an API fetch, **which updates the properties array**.  Fortunately your API should be returning the same amount of properties since the mobile number is the same, so it won't go on infinitely, but it will do the fetch twice -- once when the component mounts with 0 properties, and again after some properties have been added to the state.

I think what you intended was to fetch only if the array is empty, in which case you need to use an `if` condition inside the effect to prevent the second duplicated fetch.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("use effect");
    if ( propertyState.properties.length === 0 ) {  
      refreshView();
    }
  }, [propertyState.properties.length]);
```

You don't want to handle asynchronous tasks such as data fetching inside of a reducer.  You can do that in a Component or a Hook instead and `dispatch` an action containing the data upon completion. You can also do it in your action creators via thunk but this involves extra setup.

Something along these lines will work:

```
// reducer stores properties from an action
const propertyReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "RECEIVE_PROPERTIES":
      return {
        ...state,
        properties: action.properties
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// hook fetches an array of properties for a mobile number, stores them, and returns them
const useProperties = (mobileNumber) => {
  const { propertyState, propertyDispatch } = useContext(Context);

  // effect loads the properties for this number
  // and dispatches to store them in the state
  useEffect(
    () => {
      propertyservices
        .getPropertys(mobileNumber) //axios call that fetches data through API
        .then((response) => {
          // dispatch an action containing an array of properties
          propertyDispatch({
            type: "RECEIVE_PROPERTIES",
            properties: response.data[0].map((p) => ({
              name: p.PropertyName,
              address: {
                addressLine1: p.Line1,
                addressLine2: p.Line2,
                city: p.City,
                state: p.State,
                pin: p.Pin
              }
            }))
          });
        });
    },
    // re-run if mobileNumber changes
    // propertyDispatch won't change, but could include for completeness
    [mobileNumber]
  );

  // will always return the latest value
  return propertyState.properties;
};

// component is now focused on the presentation of data.
// it doesn't need to access the Context directly because `useProperties` handles this
const DisplayPropertys = () => {

  const properties = useProperties( '1234567890' );

  return (
    ...your JSX code...
  )
}
```

This needs better error handing and you may also want to dispatch actions like "BEGIN_FETCH" and "RECEIVE_ERROR".